# Find common items in two PowerShell arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I know there are a couple stackoverflow questions on this already but I have tried many solutions and keep getting the same error. The problem is this:

I have 2 arrays (each index represents a folder)

```
$originDirsArr = @(2, 257, 256, 3, 4, 10)
$tempDirArr = @(2, 257, 256, 3, 4)
```

I want to compare `$arr2` against `$arr1` and if there is something in `$arr1` that is not in `$arr2`, then remove it. Ie, in this situation 10 DNE in `$arr2`, so that folder should be deleted.

This is what I have tried:

```
$c = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($originDirsArr) `
 -DifferenceObject ($tempDirArr) -Passthru
$c
```

Also:

```
while ($t -lt $originDirsArr.length){
$originDirsArr[$t]
    if ( $tempDirArr -notContain $originDirsArr[$t]){
        "$_ does not exist in original and needs to be deleted"
    }else{
        "$_ does still exist in the temp"
    }
    $t++
}
```

And finally:

```
Compare-Object $originDirsArr $tempDirArr | ForEach-Object { $_.InputObject }
```

Each time I keep getting some sort of error either being the `ReferenceObject` or the `DifferenceObject` is `null`. I know that it is not `null` because I can print out the contents and even when indexed on t in that one example, I still have the contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have a bit of a distaste for `compare-object`. Since these are simple arrays, a single `foreach` loop and `-notcontains` will do the trick.

```
$originDirsArr = @(2, 257, 256, 3, 4, 10)
$tempDirArr = @(2, 257, 256, 3, 4)

foreach ($item in $originDirsArr) {
    if ($tempDirArr -notcontains $item) {
        Write-Output "Do something with $item";
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up solving it just about the same way as you mentioned. The only problem I had which came up in your way as well is I got an extra " " so that caused the program to delete the parent folder (that ended up deleting every folder) so I just threw in an -and regex to filter it out some more. But that you so much for the response. One last question if I may, when I do the remove-item it prompts the user to confirm the deletion, is there a way to avoid that? I've tried -force and -confirm with no joy. Thanks again!

Comment: never mind, did some reading and found the -confirm was causing it in the first place...oops

Answer (score 3):

Use the [HashSet generic collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). It requires .NET 3.5. It has an [IntersectWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx) method which will modify the set to include only items in both collections (i.e. like `AND`ing two collections):

```
$originDirsSet = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]' ,@(2, 257, 256, 3, 4, 10)
$tempDirSet = @(2, 257, 256, 3, 4)
$originDirsSet.IntersectWith( $tempDirSet )
# $originalDirsSet now contains 2, 257, 256, 3, 4
```

It has other set-based methods:

- `ExceptWith`: Removes all elements in the specified collection from the current `HashSet<T>` object.
- `SymmetricExceptWith`: Modifies the current `HashSet<T>` object to contain only elements that are present either in that object or in the specified collection, but not both (i.e. this is like `XOR`ing the collections).
- `UnionWith`: Modifies the current `HashSet<T>` object to contain all elements that are present in itself, the specified collection, or both (i.e. this is like `OR`ing the collections).

Comment: To avoid mutating either of the original sets, we can call [overlaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355623.aspx), which returns `True` if the sets share one or more elements, and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a 1 liner to do this.  It's the same as the accepted answer in that it iterates through one array then uses `-contains` to compare that item with the other array.  The difference here is we're using a `where-object` function and returning the result set, rather than having an if statement within a for loop.  Also making use of PowerShell's shorthand notation to reduce the amount of code (whether that's good or "bad-clever" is debatable).

```
#setting up
$originDirsArr = @(2, 257, 256, 3, 4, 10)
$tempDirArr = @(2, 257, 256, 229, 3, 4)

#get items in 1 array but not the other 
[int[]]$leftOnly = $originDirsArr | ?{$tempDirArr -notcontains $_}

#or an intersect operation
[int[]]$intersect = $originDirsArr | ?{$tempDirArr -contains $_}

#display results
"Left Only"; $leftOnly 
"Intersect"; $intersect
```

Or if this is something you're doing often, it may be useful to have a convenient function for this type of operation:

```
set-alias ?@@ Apply-ArrayOperation #http://stackoverflow.com/a/29758367/361842
function Apply-ArrayOperation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
        [object[]]$Left
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='exclude', Position=1)]
        [switch]$exclude
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='intersect', Position=1)]
        [switch]$intersect
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='outersect', Position=1)] #not sure what the correct term for this is
        [switch]$outersect
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='union', Position=1)] #not sure what the correct term for this is
        [switch]$union
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='unionAll', Position=1)] #not sure what the correct term for this is
        [switch]$unionAll
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2)]
        [object[]]$Right
    )
    begin {
        #doing this way so we can use a switch staement below, whilst having [switch] syntax for the function's caller 
        [int]$action = 1*$exclude.IsPresent + 2*$intersect.IsPresent + 3*$outersect.IsPresent + 4*$union.IsPresent + 5*$unionAll.IsPresent
    }
    process {
        switch($action) {
            1 {$Left | ?{$Right -notcontains $_}} 
            2 {$Left | ?{$Right -contains $_} }
            3 {@($Left | ?{$Right -notcontains $_}) + @($Right | ?{$Left -notcontains $_})}       
            4 {@($Left) + @($Right) | select -Unique}       
            5 {@($Left) + @($Right)}       
        }
    }
}

$array1 = @(1,3,5,7,9)
$array2 = @(2,3,4,5,6,7)

"Array 1"; $array1
"Array 1"; $array2

"Array 1 Exclude Array 2";   ?@@ $array1 -exclude $array2 
"Array 1 Intersect Array 2"; ?@@ $array1 -intersect $array2
"Array 1 Outersect Array 2"; ?@@ $array1 -outersect $array2
"Array 1 Union Array 2";     ?@@ $array1 -union $array2
"Array 1 UnionAll Array 2";  ?@@ $array1 -unionall $array2
```