# How to create a custom Powershell operator?

Tags: powershell, customization

Is it possible to create a custom operator in Powershell?  And, how would I do that?  I've searched Google but nothing is coming up.

I'm referring to specifically an infix operator:

$ExampleList **-contains** "element"

I've created cmdlets (with Powershell and C#), modules, etc., so I just need the broad strokes.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a prefix operator but not an in-fix or post-fix operator e.g.:

```
Set-Alias ?: Invoke-Ternary
function Invoke-Ternary {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [scriptblock]
    $Condition,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
    [scriptblock]
    $TrueBlock,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=2)]
    [scriptblock]
    $FalseBlock,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ParameterSetName='InputObject')]
    [psobject]
    $InputObject
)

Process {
    if ($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'InputObject') {
        Foreach-Object $Condition -input $InputObject | Foreach {
            if ($_) {
                Foreach-Object $TrueBlock -InputObject $InputObject
            }
            else {
                Foreach-Object $FalseBlock -InputObject $InputObject
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (&$Condition) {
        &$TrueBlock
    }
    else {
        &$FalseBlock
    }
}
```

Use like so:

```
$toolPath = ?: {[IntPtr]::Size -eq 4} {"$env:ProgramFiles(x86)\Tools"} {"$env:ProgramFiles\Tools"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

After thinking on it, this is what I came up with:

Not sure if it's a better answer than Jon Tirjan's

```
function Op {
    Param (
        # this operator is the reverse of -contains
        [switch] $isIn,

        # this operator is just an example 
        [switch] $Plus
    )

    if ($isIn) {
        if ($args.Length -ne 2) {
            throw "Requires two arguments"
        }

        return ($args[1] -contains $args[0])
    }
    elseif ($Plus) {
        if ($args.Length -ne 2) {
            throw "Requires two arguments"
        }

        return ($args[0] + $args[1])
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
PS> $ExampleList = @("alpha", "bravo", "charlie")

PS> Op "alpha" -isIn $ExampleList
True

PS> Op "delta" -isIn $ExampleList
False

PS> Write-Host ("Answer: " + (Op 5 -plus 7))
Answer: 12
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really late to the game.. but figured I would offer a nasty hack alternative.. The only benefit would be to make something that "looks" similar to the C# operator.

```
    Set-Alias ?: Invoke-Ternary
    Function Invoke-Ternary {
      [cmdletbinding()]
      param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [object]$Condition,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [Alias('FirstExpression')]
        [object]$Consequent,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [Alias('SecondExpression')]
        [object]$Alternative
      )
      $isTrue = if($Condition.GetType().Name -eq 'Scriptblock'){ 
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Condition 
      } else { 
        $Condition 
      }
      if ($isTrue) {
        if($Consequent.GetType().Name -eq 'Scriptblock'){
          Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Consequent
        } else {
          $Consequent
        }
      } else { 
        if($Alternative.GetType().Name -eq 'Scriptblock'){
          Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Alternative
        } else {
          $Alternative
        }
      }
    }
    {[IntPtr]::Size -eq 4} |?: 'I like Soup' {'test'|?: 3  ('{0} prefer toast' -f 'We')}
    {[IntPtr]::Size -eq 8} |?: 'I like Soup' {$false|?: 3  ('{0} prefer toast' -f 'We')}
```

While this is really nothing more than string mangling of the first expression separated by a semicolon (in favor of a colon), it illustrates that there are multiple ways to accomplish this behavior.
That all being said.. I would LOVE to have official operators created for
the Ternary and the Null-Coalescing operators.. While I am at it.. an official Use-Object (using statement (not directive)) would be nice as well. Until then I will continue with my little hacks, but its nice to dream.

Comment: It's helpful for readability of answer to use the Editor's "Code" function which will put your entire code segment as a single code block, instead of just backticking each line.

Comment: @ProgrammerDan I did an edit for it.  It is in queue now

Comment: While I like the idea of splitting the string, using regex to evaluate expressions gets messy VERY quickly.. For instance what if your expression included string formatting?

However you were right that I wasn't evaluating the Condition correctly in the previous code.
see the updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cmdlet and pipe the list into it.
For evaluating a list, be sure to use the `End` function instead of `Process`.
`Process` will automatically iterate the collection, which you don't want here.

Your script would look something like this:

```
$ExampleList | Test-Contains "element"
```

Comment: That's a good point, piping kind of makes every cmdlet an infix operator